# Rails Application keep heating pg_type and pg_attribute table how to reduse this call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using ruby ruby-2.1.2, Rails 4.1.3 with Postgres and we see application keep heating pg_type and pg_attribute table.

How to validate and see who calling this query?

```
Query 1 : SELECT oid, typname, typelem, typdelim, typinput FROM pg_type
Query 2 :  SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = ?::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > ? AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Comment: Do you see these queries in the logs? Or where did you get these from?

Comment: I see this query in the Query review tool :https://github.com/ankane/pghero/blob/master/guides/Docker.md 
And also in AWS RDS Performance Insights

Comment: Do you want to see what part of the application is calling this and not the "user" right? :)

Comment: Yes I like to know what part of the application is calling and why and why with that high frequency what I see in query analyze tool it calls 34%  or overall query and i see it was 3k 1/min

Comment: Ok, let's see if my answer helps @jayesh

Comment: Any news with this? Did marginalia helped you figure out the places queries are called?

Answer (score 2):

Rails itself calls that to resolve the rails models. It's how it understands what types are in your model. You can create a schema file by running `rake db:schema:cache:dump` which will make rails load that instead of asking the db over time.

Comment: rake db:schema:cache:dump not work for postgress DB

Answer (score 0):

For development (also production error tracking) you can use [marginalia](https://github.com/basecamp/marginalia)

It will attach comments in the SQL queries with data about controller and action_name. Here is how it looks for one of my apps:

[image]

Alternatively, for more serious tracking and performance optimization, I'd choose to make an account on [newrelic](https://newrelic.com/). They provide all kinds of high quality insights and custom instrumentation about your app.